# How to order the rows with respect to multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How to order the rows with respect to multiple columns such that the ordering maintains the condition that if two people have the same details they get the same rank. I will give an example to illustrate :Here firstly ordering is done by score and in case of tie with penalty and still if tie exist both are given same rank and next person gets the adjusted rank.

```
###################
rank roll score penalty
 1    11    3     23
 2    12    3     20
 2    13    3     20
 2    14    3     20
 5    15    2     10
```

So the question is how to fill the rank column??If not possible in mysql what is the other alternative??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test data:

```
/*
drop table test;
create table test (roll int, score int, penalty int);
insert into test (roll, score, penalty) values (11, 3, 23), (12, 3, 20), (13, 3, 20), (14,3,20), (15, 2, 10);
*/
```

And here it comes:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN `rank` int FIRST;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_test LIKE test;
INSERT INTO tmp_test (`rank`, roll, score, penalty)
SELECT cast(q.`rank` as unsigned integer) as `rank`, roll, score, penalty FROM (
SELECT IF(@prev != CONCAT(sq.score, '_', sq.penalty), @rownum:=@rownum2, @rownum) AS rank, 
@prev:=CONCAT(sq.score, '_', sq.penalty), 
@rownum2:=@rownum2 + 1,
sq.*
FROM (
  SELECT
  roll, score, penalty
  FROM
  test
  , (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prev:='', @rownum2:=1) r 
  ORDER BY score DESC, penalty DESC
) sq
) q;

UPDATE test t INNER JOIN tmp_test tt ON t.roll = tt.roll AND t.score = tt.score AND t.penalty = tt.penalty
SET t.rank = tt.rank;
/*optionally...*/    
DROP TABLE tmp_test;
```

You need to work with a temporary table here, because you can't update the table you are reading from. The temporary table will be automatically deleted when the session ends.

Comment: It is not giving the 5th rank to roll 15..It is giving the 3rd rank to it

Comment: @HarshKhandelwal Sorry, corrected it now and tested. Works fine for me.

Comment: How have u tested ? ? To me the rank column shows BLOB data .. What I want is after these queries the rank column must have the ranks as described

Comment: @HarshKhandelwal That's just your strange client or phpmyadmin or whatever you are using, that doesn't want to display it. Edited my answer to fix that. BLOB is short for Binary large object, which is a mistake by your client. On console it displays fine. Anyway, definitely works now.

Comment: But again..could u just make this change permanent..It is just displaying the ranks , not updating it

Comment: @HarshKhandelwal You didn't mention that before. Added that. For that extra effort you could at least upvote my answer (and accept).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @row = 0; 
select min(a.Row) as Rank, s.Roll, s.Score, s.Penalty
from (
    select @row := @row + 1 AS Row, 
        Roll, 
        Score, 
        Penalty
    from Score
    order by Score desc, Penalty desc
) a
inner join Score s on a.Score = s.Score and a.Penalty = s.Penalty
group by Roll, Score, Penalty
order by min(Row)
```

Comment: It is not working....It is giving differnt ranks to the same score and penalty..And how to make the updation of the rank??When i refresh the page(of PHPMYadmin) I get the same null value for the rank column

Comment: Sorry, no MySQL server to test on, and it seems SQL Fiddle can't handle the code. @Jake Feasel

Comment: No, it's not. Because a) you provided no schema, so I assumed Rank was a derived column, b) you did not explicitly ask for how to do an INSERT statement (a differenet question), and c) you should not persist derivable data unless necessary for performance reasons.

Comment: but i need the ranks in some other application...And I asked how to fill the rank columns in the question also...Please help me ..

Comment: @HarshKhandelwal Use my query with an UPDATE statement

Comment: @RedFilter Sorry about that - I've fixed the bug with the MySQL code to work correctly in this case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db26/4